# Windows Server 2012 Networking Drivers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I'm doing testwork for a potential switch to Windows 10 for our school in the future, and I am using two Lenovo E450 laptops for both the client [Windows 10] and server [2012 R2]. I was able to install the network drivers for the client computer just fine, however for whatever reason when I try on the server computer, the driver says that it successfully installed, but the system will not acknowledge that it is, and thus I have gotten stuck.

I've tried many different drivers and versions for this particular machine, but nothing has worked so far. Is there a driver I have to have installed first to get the other network drivers to install or is it maybe just not supported? Thanks

-MP

Answer (score 0):

What version of driver are you installing ?

Windows 2012R2 drivers are compatible with windows 8.1 drivers, so use some W8.1 drivers and they should work fine. Other versions may install but could not work, just like in your situation.

Comment: I have tried pretty much every version that there is on Lenovo's support website, and have just retried the 8.1 version, however, in the device manager it doesn't see it as an actual "component" per se, but rather has an "Ethernet Controller" in the Other Devices category. It's worth noting that the driver installs to the drivers folder, but if I run the autorun that is inside to install the drivers (again?) it has a popup saying "Cannot install drivers. No Intel(R) Adapters are present in this computer."

Comment: Could it somehow not be intel but a realtek NIC ?

Comment: I'm almost 100 percent sure it's Intel, I've installed the same/similar drivers onto the client computer using Intel drivers, and they're the same model computer, so they should theoretically be the same. I haven't opened it up myself to look myself though.